# Limit instantiations of class with particular value to one - django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

I have two classes in a django app, `project` and `plan`

The project class has an `is_global` boolean field, as does the plan class. The plan also has a foreign key to the project class (projects have multiple plans).

I am trying to accomplish the following: for both projects and plans, there should only ever be one instance of each where `is_global = true`. The global plan should belong to the global project.

Is it possible to enforce this logic with django models?

Comment: It sounds like the boolean flag is a poor and precarious way to capture this. Why not just separately store the ID of the "global" project?

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite the save function of each model to check for prior 'is_global' items

Project Model

```
def save(self):
    if self.is_global:
        other_global = Project.objects.filter(is_global=True).exists()
        if other_global:
            #handle the error, eg, raise an exception or send a message
            return
    super.save()
```

Plan model

```
def save(self):
    if self.is_global:
        other_global = Plan.objects.filter(is_global=True).exists()
        if other_global:
            #handle the error, eg, raise an exception or send a message
            return
        if not self.project.is_global:
            #handle the error, eg, raise an exception or send a message
            return 
    super.save()
```